# c# Killing an app each time another instance is launched

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I have a c# application that open files from command line ... 
for example if i type :

myApp.exe filepath/file.jpg

A jpg will be opened in a window. My issue is that if i type a second time this command the new file is not loaded. I would like to kill the existing process in a method that checks if the instance is unique...

I try to maintain someone else code and i'm stuck (1st day on c#)...

Here is the updated code i changed :

```
protected void SingleInstanceStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(appPath);
    //StartWithShellExecuteEx(processStartInfo);

    myLog.Log("Création du mutex", LogType.Debug);
    bool hasHandle = false;
    _mutex = new Mutex(true, _applicationUniqueName, out hasHandle);
    _args = e.Args;

    Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName();
    int count = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length;
    myLog.Info("# Actual currentProcess.Id : " + currentProcess.Id);

    if (hasHandle && count < 2) // Premier lancement
    {
        var mw = new MainWindow();

        mw.Closing += mainWindow_Closing;
        mw.Loaded += mainWindow_Loaded;

        myLog.Log("Lancement du serveur de named pipe", LogType.Debug);
        Server(_applicationUniqueName, mw);

        myLog.Log("Affichage de la fenêtre du programme", LogType.Debug);
        myLog.Info("# Actual if hasHandle currentProcess.Id : " + currentProcess.Id);
        mw.Show();
        myLog.Info("# Actual if hasHandle after show() currentProcess.Id : " + currentProcess.Id);
    }
    else // Lancement secondaire
    {
        // Current.Shutdown(0);
        myLog.Info("# In SingleInstanceStartup - Killed process with pId : " + currentProcess.Id);
        RestartApp(currentProcess.Id, _applicationUniqueName);
    }
}

// kill to restart ... 
public void RestartApp(int pid, string applicationName)
{
    // Wait for the process to terminate
    Process process = null;
    try
    {    
        process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        myLog.Info("# In RestartApp - Killed processId : " + pid );
        process.Kill();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        myLog.Log(ex.Message);
    }
    Process.Start(applicationName, "");
}
```

I wonder why i kill the last process i create ... If i launch the app I have a pid = 4566 and I kill the pid of the instance i create after ... for example pid = 45799

Comment: Seems like in the method "RestartApp" you don't kill the proceess, but wait it to complete. Could you please try "process.Kill()" instead of "process.WaitForExit(1000)" and let us know what happens?

Comment: Are you passing the file route throught arguments at `Process.Start(applicationName, "");` ? I think the error is because the file route is not found, maybe because it is not set again on the restart.

Comment: In fact i'm killing a pid but i just kill the one i create ... not the one which is running. I'm going to update my code above ...

Comment: It's usually a better user experience if you pass your new command line to the old instance (via some form of IPC) and then exit yourself. If the user has, for example, repositioned the window onto a second monitor, they may not appreciate that repositioned window disappearing and a new one appearing back on the primary monitor.

Comment: the position is saved in a config file ... i wouldn't do this if i could refresh the view ...

Answer (score 0):

I found out an easy solution ... Ugly but do what it must do ...

```
protected void SingleInstanceStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   Process[] tbPro = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

   foreach(Process p in tbPro)
   {
       if(p.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
       {
           p.Kill();
       }
    }
    myLog.Log("Création du mutex", LogType.Debug);
    _mutex = new Mutex(true, _applicationUniqueName);
    _args = e.Args;

    var mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.Closing += mainWindow_Closing;
    mw.Loaded += mainWindow_Loaded;
    myLog.Log("Lancement du serveur de named pipe", LogType.Debug);
    Server(_applicationUniqueName, mw);

    mw.Show();
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to create/use a Mutex with this solution.

Comment: Indeed... It seems that the Mutex escaped my eye of the tiger :) thanks ! I tested without ... and works fine !